# How to save localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How to save user data in localstorage even after refreshing

```js
localStorage.setItem('bas',JSON.stringify(basketList));
```

```js
const objectorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
```

Which command is more correct for storage?

Answer (score 2):

This command `localStorage.setItem('bas',JSON.stringify(basketList));` use to save data to localStorage with key is `bas`.

And this command `localStorage.getItem('bas')` is get data from localStorage with key is `bas`.

localStorage storage string data. So you get data from localStorage, you need parse it to object using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bas'));`.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok.

To **save** a new object in localstorage use:

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
```

To **get** an existing object in localstorage use:

```
const myuserdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

For more info check
[setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)
[getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Answer (score 0):

> Which command is more correct for storage?

None of them is "more correct" than the other. They are two different commands with different purposes:

- [localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) stores data in the local storage under the provided `keyName`.
- [localStorage.getItem(keyName)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) retrieves the value stored under the provided `keyName`.

So, in your code:

```js
localStorage.setItem('bas',JSON.stringify(basketList));
const objectorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object'));
```

The first command stores the stringified `basketList` under the key `bas`. The second command tries to get the value stored under the key `object`, which **doesn't exist** in this case. The second command should instead be:

```js
const objectorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bas'));
```

Answer (score -1):

According to Geeksforgeeks, localStorage has no expiration time.

You can test it with these steps:

1. Set an Item

`basketList = ['a','b']; localStorage.setItem('bas',JSON.stringify(basketList));`

2. Refresh it and print the value

   `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bas'));`

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/localstorage-and-sessionstorage-web-storage-apis/#:~:text=LocalStorage%20has%20no%20expiration%20time,the%20user%20manually%20delete%20it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/localstorage-and-sessionstorage-web-storage-apis/#:%7E:text=LocalStorage%20has%20no%20expiration%20time,the%20user%20manually%20delete%20it).